# Ensure queued messages are sent in correct order

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I have a client-server architecture, communicating using TCP. The client sends messages to the client at a rate of 1msg/70ms. The server must simulate network latency, so on the server-receive side of things, I do the following:

```
//Event handler for new messages
private void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    //Add raw data to a queue for processing at a later time
    TemporaryRawMessages.Enqueue(args.Bytes);
    args.Recycle();
}

//Function running on thread; processes newly arrived raw messages
//new messages are removed from the queue, given their own thread and processed independently. 
void ProcessMessagesIn()
{
    while (true)
    {

        if (TemporaryRawMessages.Count > 0)
        {
            var raw = TemporaryRawMessages.Dequeue();
            var t = new Thread(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(LatencyUp);
                var message = (ClientToServerMessage)Utils.Deserialize(raw_message);
                Messages_In.Enqueue(message);
            });
            t.Start();
        }

    }
}

//Create & start a thread to processes incoming messages
var processMessagesIn = new Thread(ProcessMessagesIn);
processMessagesIn.Start();
```

Notice the `LatencyUp` variable. I want messages from the client to be delayed b x milliseconds, but evenly spaced at 1msg/70ms. In other words, all messages are 70ms apart, but offset by `LatencyUp`.

I also add a delay to message going out of the server to the client, to represent the network down latency:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SendLoop(); });

void SendToClient(ServerToClientMessage message)
{
    Messages_Out.Enqueue(message);
}

void SendLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(Messages_Out.Count > 0)
        {
            ServerToClientMessage message_out = null;
            Messages_Out.TryDequeue(out message_out);

            if(message_out != null)
            {
                Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(LatencyDown);
                    if (ClientConnection != null && ClientConnection.State == ConnectionState.Connected)
                    {
                        var serialized = Utils.Serialize(message);
                        ClientConnection.SendBytes(serialized, SendOption.Reliable);
                    }
                });

                myNewThread.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried sending like this, without the queue for message from server to client:

```
void SendToClient(ServerToClientMessage message)
{
    Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(LatencyDown);
        Send(message);
    });

    myNewThread.Start();
}
```

**The problem**

Sometimes messages from the server to the client are being mixed up... for example, message 2 might be sent before message 1.

I'm not entirely sure why. The messages are being put into the queue in the correct order (I've checked this). Somewhere between adding to the queue and dequeuing + sending, something goes wrong.

The only thing I can think of is that a thread completes before another, but I can't think how this would happen.

What can I do to ensure that messages are received in the order they were sent (client to server) and are sent in the correct order from the server to the client?

Performance (in terms of processing speed) is important, so any improvements/suggestions regarding that topic would also be appreciated.

Comment: You're starting a thread for each message, so yeah, that can introduce latency in and of itself causing one thread to finish before an earlier started one. Why are you using a thread per message, and not a single message sending thread?

Comment: Because I need to delay my messages by some offset. If I had 1 thread, each message would be spaced by 70ms + `LatencyDown`. I need them to be 70ms apart, but offset with a delay of `LatencyDown`.

Comment: I don't know how you went from _"I need an offset"_ to _"I'll use a thread per message"_, but you need to revise that design.

Comment: Every time you Sleep() your thread is put on hold and later queued for reactivation. The Thread ready-queue does not promise fairness.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  Are you doing the assignment correctly.  I'm not sure how you can simulate TCP latency using TCP connection.  I would think you would be simulating TCP connection by using a FIFO.  You cannot control the timing of a connection nor a stream because windows is using a timer in the stream class to move data (the Timer Tick Server).  So data is not going to be spaced uniformly.

Comment: If you need to send messages in a sequential order, they must be queued. Nothing guarantees that hundreds of newly created threads will get executed in the order of their creation. Also, `while (true)` is only good for warming your room on a cold winter night, and decreasing the lifespan of your CPU.

Comment: @jdweng No, not a school assignment. This is a personal project. What if I created a queue of worker threads and reuse them, rather than creating a new thread for each message?

Comment: @Groo the messages are queued, in the correct order.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, that is what I suspected - threads introducing latency. However, I'm not sure how to go about it in another way.

Comment: @pookie: your question suggests they aren't.

Comment: @Groo I stated that messages are queued in the correct order and that I have checked this. They are being sent in the wrong order after being dequeued, likely something to do with thread B terminating before thread A.

Comment: `new Thread(() => fifo.Enqueue(x));` cannot ensure correct order. Threads aren't executed sequentially, hence whatever they do in the background isn't executed sequentially. Also keep in mind that every time you create a new thread, you get a lot of CPU overhead (for creating the thread, instead of using the `ThreadPool`) and memory overhead (1MB of stack is allocated for each newly created thread by default).

Comment: @Groo Thanks, I didn't realise that.

Comment: It will be hard to get precise spacing between packets.  Maybe you want to add a timestamp to each thread and then simulate by processing data using timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple threads to dispatch events in a sequential order. If you want to have an asynchronous consumer for your data producer, all you need is a single thread.

The simplest way to create a producer-consumer queue is using the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>();

// this is a single, one and only producer thread
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var number = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        number++;
        Console.WriteLine("tx --> " + number);
        blockingCollection.Add(number);
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    }
});

// single, one and only consumer thread
foreach (var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    Task.Delay(200).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item + " --> rx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.

Comment: Aah but this won't work... it will just put a 200ms delay between messages in the foreach and add another message in 1s, so each message will be separated by a delay of 1.2s.

Comment: @pookie: both messages should be separated by 1s if I am not mistaken. The rx part is just offseted by 200ms. But anyway this is the general idea, you only need two different threads (producer + consumer).